# How can I use OpenSSL from Linux Terminal to encrypt all files in one folder to another folder?

Tags: linux, openssl

How can I use OpenSSL from Linux Terminal to encrypt all files in one folder to another folder?

Hello,

I am using OpenSSL from a Linux Terminal.

I have a folder "A" and I want to encrypt all files from that folder into folder "B" using AES256.

Anyone knows how to do this?

Vesa

Comment: It is not a duplicate because this is an OpenSSL specific question. Not interested in GPG solutions.

Comment: There are several OpenSSL answers in the linked question.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is probably the openssl `enc` utility. `enc` allows you to perform various stream cipher routines. It only works on files. This is not much of a problem though, we just have to archive the directory first, using `tar`. If we want to encrypt and decrypt using AES256:

## Encrypting a directory

- `tar -vcf directory.tar directory/`
- `openssl aes256 -salt -in directory.tar -out encrypted_dir.aes256`

## Decrypt the directory

- `openssl aes256 -d -salt -in encrypted_dir.aes256 -out unencrypted.tar`
- `tar --one-top-level -xvf unencrypted.tar`

(The `--one-top-level` flag is not strictly necessary, but it creates a new directory called `unencrypted` where the contents then land, which is nice to have in my opinion.)

If you encrypt and decrypt the way as above, you'll just get asked a password. You can also use a keyfile or similar, just look at `man enc` for more detailed information. Also note that you should always use `-salt` when you encrypt with a password, because of dictionary attacks (`-salt` is actually the default, but it's not a bad idea to spell it out to make sure).

Comment: Will test it today or later this week